# Scroll bar not Visible - Stack Pannel

Tags: c#, .net, windows-store-apps, windows-store

```
<StackPanel Name="CurrentInvoice" Margin="118,165,119,58" Opacity="100" Background="White">
        <TextBlock Name="Status" FontSize="16" Foreground="GreenYellow"/>
        <ListView Name="Invoices" Width="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1000">
                        <Border Background="#FF91C919" Width="102">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TransactionHeaderId}" Margin="21,0,0,0" Foreground="White"  FontSize="30" Width="81" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Height="35"></TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Background="#FFF99B9B" Width="102">
                            <Button Foreground="White" Height="20" Width="55" Content="{Binding TransactionHeaderId}" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Click="InvoiceOpen_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="16,0,10,7" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                        <Image Source="Assets/moreIcon.png"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                            </Button>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

The above coding is for displaying items inside the stack panel, but I'm unable to add a scroll bar. I used Scrollviewer too. There is no effect with that.All the overflow is hidden. Please find me a way to add a Scroll bar.(Vertical / Horizontal)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
 <StackPanel Name="CurrentInvoice" Margin="118,165,119,58" Opacity="100" Background="White">
    <TextBlock Name="Status" FontSize="16" Foreground="GreenYellow"/>
    <ListView Name="Invoices" Width="1000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionMode="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="1000">
                    <Border Background="#FF91C919" Width="102">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TransactionHeaderId}" Margin="21,0,0,0" Foreground="White"  FontSize="30" Width="81" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Segoe UI" Height="35"></TextBlock>
                    </Border>
                    <Border Background="#FFF99B9B" Width="102">
                        <Button Foreground="White" Height="20" Width="55" Content="{Binding TransactionHeaderId}" Command="{Binding TestCommand}" Click="InvoiceOpen_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="16,0,10,7" BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                    <Image Source="Assets/moreIcon.png"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </Border>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
 </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Set HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"

Answer (score 0):

Put the StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer like this with both VerticalScrollBarVisibility and HorizontalScrollBarVisibility set to visible.

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
            <StackPanel Name="CurrentInvoice" Opacity="100" Background="White">
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Black" FontSize="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Black" FontSize="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Black" FontSize="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Black" FontSize="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Black" FontSize="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Black" FontSize="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Black" FontSize="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Black" FontSize="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Black" FontSize="40"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Test" Foreground="Black" FontSize="40"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </ScrollViewer>
```

If you don't want the scrollbars to visible all the time, set those two settings to Auto.